# Get user detail from Ad/Exchange online using jquery

Tags: office365, sharepoint-online

I have list of users in Ad/Exchange online that we can view from https://portal.office.com/Admin/Default.aspx#ActiveUsersPage . I want to get some details (office phone, fax) for a specific user from SharePoint site. Is it possible? 
In other words, i am running javascript from mysite.sharepoint.com/sitepages/test.aspx and want to show an user detail that we have in https://portal.office.com/Admin/Default.aspx#ActiveUsersPage

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/howto/office-365-unified-api-overview  [User](https://msdn.microsoft.com/office/office365/HowTo/office-365-unified-api-reference#msg_ref_entityType_User) should give you the details you are looking for.  This API is currently in public preview and applies to only Office 365 users.  If you are looking for an API that can be used in production, please use [Azure AD Graph API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn151678.aspx).